# Error: Program type already present: android.support.annotation.AnyRes

Tags: android, android-studio, build

**err msg**

[image]

I am getting the following error while i run the project when i add this code in build.gradle :
"//Fresco
    `api 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:1.11.0'"`

I am using, 
**Android Studio** 3.1.4 
**Build** #AI-173.4907809, built on July 24, 2018 
**JRE**: 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b02 amd64 
**JVM**: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o 
**Windows** 10 10.0

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 19
        //noinspection OldTargetApi
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
            ndk{
                //设置支持的SO库架构
                abiFilters "armeabi", "armeabi-v7a", "arm64-v8a", "x86","arm64-v8a","x86_64"
            }
            javaCompileOptions {
                annotationProcessorOptions {
                    arguments = [AROUTER_MODULE_NAME: project.getName()]
                }
            }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    api fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    api 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    api 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    api 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    api 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'
    api 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.1.1'
    api 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    api 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    api 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    //retrofit2依赖
    api 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
    //okhttp3依赖
    api 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.11.0'
    //okhttp3网络拦截器依赖
    api 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.5.0'
    //rxJava依赖
    api 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.17'
    api 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.2'
    //retrofit2解析器依赖
    api 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'
    api 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.3.0'
    //json解析依赖
    api 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
    //log日志管理
    api 'com.orhanobut:logger:2.2.0'
    //腾讯开源UI库
    api 'com.qmuiteam:qmui:1.1.3'
    //基础工具库
    api 'com.github.vondear.RxTool:RxKit:v2.2.7'
    api 'com.github.vondear.RxTool:RxArcGisKit:v2.2.7'
    api 'com.blankj:utilcode:1.20.3'
    //高德地图
    api 'com.amap.api:3dmap:5.0.0'
    api 'com.amap.api:location:3.3.0'
    //ARouter
    api 'com.alibaba:arouter-api:1.4.0'
    api 'com.alibaba:arouter-annotation:1.0.6'
    annotationProcessor 'com.alibaba:arouter-compiler:1.2.1'
    //Fresco
    api 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:1.11.0'
}
```